# update submodule in git desktop of Mac

Tags: git

I am a newbie in git. In a repository, I have modified a file `biblio.bib` in a submodule and now I need to upload it to github. However, I met the following problem when I click "commit to master":
[image]

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to stage the changes first.**

Not sure about the GUI, but in CLI you would add the submodule:

```
git add <submodule_name>
```